# How do you test an abstract class in Enzyme and/or pass implicit variables?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have a base class that's being extended by several components, and inside that base class, there's an implicit variable that is being passed in from the classes that are extending it. For instance, I have the following as the base class:

```
export default class BaseCard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.hasData && <span> Has Content </span>}
      </div>);
  }
}
```

And the component that extends the BaseCard:

```
export default class MyCard extends BaseCard {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.hasData = true;
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          MyCard content
        </div>);
    }
}
```

`this.hasData` is defined inside the `MyCard` component, but since I'm testing `BaseCard`, it's not defined inside the class, and therefore, I can't test parts of the DOM that depend on that variable being there. How can I pass it in when testing with Enzyme?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the variable on the instance like this:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyCard />);
wrapper.instance().hasData = true;
```